# How in solar 2d to save files on different devices (Android, Ios, Windows) to downloads in internal storage?

Tags: lua, solar2d

I need to save it in an application created in solar 2d, so that after saving it, it appears in downloads as a downloaded file

I haven't found anything on the internet about this